# How to make blog post article title go to their permalink

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently using this code to try and link to a blog articles URL.

```
<a href="<?php get_permalink(); ?>">
 <span class="white"><?php the_title(); ?></span></p>
</a>
```

This code is on the main blog page and when I currently click the post title it directs me to the main blog page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the_permalink() instead, or add echo before get_permalink().

Using get_permalink() will retrieve the URL for the post but not display it.

Comment: Thanks this solution was helpful

Answer (score 0):

Pass `$postId` in `get_permalink` function. `get_permalink($postId)`

```
<a href="<?php get_permalink($postId); ?>">
    <span class="white"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
</a>
```